# Can someone briefly explain what the use of this kit is?

Tags: identification

I have no idea what this kit would be used for. (Asking for a friend...)
[image: Inside of box]
[image: Box cover]
[image: Details 1 of 2]
[image: Details 2 of 2]

Comment: Not sure.  Could be it was a kit of demo parts a salesman used.

Comment: Looks like a retirement present.

Comment: Contact sales@trak.com. Phone: (813) 901-7200 Toll Free: (888) 283-8444

Comment: From the seriously worn appearance of the left-hand side of the foam insert,I would say that those objects have been removed and put back in place a large number of few times.

Comment: Demo kit where the parts on the left were used more often, and the foam has degenerated over time from the sweat and grease from fingers.

Comment: @Andy aka :  The friend in question is going to contact the company. I'll let you know their answer...

Comment: The foam probably deteriorated from age not use.

Comment: @RobertMiller Is your friend trying to develop some kind of provenances to show that this is an important bit of history and worth being sold to collectors? Or is there some other purpose to this investigation? (I'm just curious. If I'm prying too much, please feel free to say so. I won't be offended at all.)

Comment: @ jonk : She's cleaning out her grandfather's house and found this, I expect that she would be also interested in it's value...

Comment: @RobertMiller To put this in my words, "She isn't directly interested but also doesn't want to throw away something that may be of interest to others. If a few dollars arrived as a result of protecting it, so much the better. But she'd like to get a good home for it, regardless, if such exists." Maybe I'm just projecting, though. Anyway, I think you may find some folks sufficiently knowledgeable to help you with this at the [Tek Museum](https://vintagetek.org/). They are serious ***and*** knowledgeable about stuff like this. Give them a call. They share their knowledge freely and eagerly.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a sales kit that a factory rep would take with him or her when they visited a customer (perhaps with the distributor rep in tow).

Not everything is (err was) done online in industry.